# How to detect if gradle plugin is running inside of Intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

How can I detect if a gradle build script is running inside of Intellij? I'd like to change the project setup slightly to optimise and workaround issues for IDE users.

If I have the Android plugin installed then I can use, but without that plugin there isn't an obvious hook.

```
properties.containsKey('android.injected.invoked.from.ide')
```

Background: I have a Gradle build with source mapped twice, it's because of a module building a Graal native test launcher. This isn't ideal but is a separate discussion and relates to limitations of the various plugins (junit 5 + graal).

```
09:38   Duplicate content roots detected
            Path [/home/yschimke/okhttp/okhttp-dnsoverhttps/src/test/java] of module [okhttp-parent.native-image-tests.main] was removed from modules [okhttp-parent.okhttp-dnsoverhttps.test]
            Also 4 more paths were deduplicated. See idea log for details
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure gradle plugin based on future tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63409895/configure-gradle-plugin-based-on-future-tasks)

Comment: Evaluate `idea.active` system property, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63411337/2000323

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-conditional-test-execution

Use the XPC_SERVICE_NAME environment property on Mac, and on Windows IDEA_INITIAL_DIRECTORY

```
def isIDE = properties.containsKey('android.injected.invoked.from.ide') ||
        (System.getenv("XPC_SERVICE_NAME") ?: "").contains("intellij")
        (System.getenv("XPC_SERVICE_NAME") ?: "").contains("intellij") ||
        System.getenv("IDEA_INITIAL_DIRECTORY") != null
```

Latter comes from https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/f396a4f0777cc1e79908a637f9f814eda794d3f8/native/WinLauncher/WinLauncher/WinLauncher.cpp#L1199

Comment: On macOS, I also added the check for the `__CFBundleIdentifier` environment variable, the value of which is `com.jetbrains.intellij`. Because `XPC_SERVICE_NAME` could be `0` sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Another one I found is,

```
isIDEA = System.getProperty("idea.fatal.error.notification") != null
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can find interesting properties using

```kotlin
System.getProperties().forEach { (t, any) -> println("$t : $any") }
```

For example : `idea.active : true`, or `idea.version : 2023.2`