# How to remove version from IntelliJ IDEA Gradle artifacts?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Given a (versioned) Gradle project that builds a war, I want to deploy it to a local tomcat using IntelliJ IDEA.

This works fine at the moment, except the name of the IntelliJ artifact generated by the [Gradle IntelliJ plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html) includes the version number of my project. This means at each release I need to update the Tomcat run configuration in IntelliJ (even worse, each time I switch branch, e.g. when doing bugfixes in 1.2.x and new features in 1.x…).

It seems I need to specify the artifact name in “Run > Edit Configurations… > Tomcat > Deployment tab”, so I’m currently looking for a way to remove the version number from that artifact name. However, being able to say “use whatever artifact from current project” (e.g. with a regex) would also be fine.

So far, I tried to ignore the IntelliJ artifacts generated by the Gradle IntelliJ plugin and instead configure my own artifact in “Project Settings > Artifacts”. This also “works”, but as I couldn’t find a way to tell IntelliJ to put “all runtime dependencies of module X” in WEB-INF/lib, I had to give it the list of those dependencies. So now, instead of being required to update my configuration each time my project version changes, I need to do it each time a dependency changes.

NB: I’m using the Gradle plugin bundled in IntelliJ, not the [IDEA Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider renaming the war artifact to exclude the version from it. To make this build logic active only in IntelliJ IDEA you can by checking the `idea.sync.active` (and `idea.active` if you are runing a Gradle task from IDE) property in a build script (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63411337/2000323):

```
war {
    if (System.getProperty('idea.active')) {
        archiveFileName = 'myname.war'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could pass a flag in release / continuous integration builds so you can skip the config in those cases. Then you could do something like the following in your build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war' 

if (!project.jenkinsFlag) {
   war {
      archiveFileName = "{project.name}.war"
   }
}
```

See [War.archiveFileName](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War:archiveFileName)

Answer (score 0):

## First solution

I first did the opposite of what [lance-java](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1089967/lance-java) suggested (but I found this solution thanks to his tip):

```
def warNameProperty = "${project.name}.war.name"
if (project.hasProperty(warNameProperty)) {
  war {
    archiveFileName = project.property(warNameProperty)
  }
}
```

Then, setting that property to a specific value inside my `gradle.properties` (the one in my user home) did the trick.

## Final solution

However, thanks to [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2000323/andrey) I ended up using a solution that allows me to still have the version number included when running gradle tasks from the command line:

```
war {
  if (System.getProperty('idea.active')) {
    archiveFileName = "${project.name}.war"
  }
}
```

Note that I first checked the `idea.sync.active` property. This allowed me to configure the tomcat deployment in IntelliJ with a Gradle artifact that had no version number in its name. However, since by default IDEA uses Gradle (with only the `idea.active` property set) to build the artifact prior to deployment, the build would generate an artifact with a different name and thus deployment would fail.